# Cancel failed reverse-i-search in bash but keep what I typed in

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

I hit Ctrl+R pretty much every time I run a command, but after typing in a word (e.g. find) I realize that the command is not in my history so I get this as expected:

```
(failed reverse-i-search)`find`: cat fire.txt
```

Now how do I cancel the search but keep 'find' in my command line? No matter what key I press 'cat fire.txt' ends up on my command line and I have to erase and re-type my command again.

I am using Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: To cancel the search without auto-completing you can use `Ctrl+g`, but this won't retain your search term.

Comment: this is really essential. As it stands it expects me to remember whats in the history before I try search for it. Unlike the non-obstructive auto-complete

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can do what you want exactly but you can get something vaguely close (though it sacrifices other features of reverse-i-search).

Bind a key sequence to [`history-search-backward`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html#index-history_002dsearch_002dbackward-_0028_0029) and do your searches by typing the starting word and then hitting your bound sequence.

> history-search-backward ()
>
> Search backward through the history for the string of characters between the start of the current line and the point. The search string must match at the beginning of a history line. This is a non-incremental search. By default, this command is unbound.

But that only works for commands that start with the word you are searching for (as well as not being incremental).

Update: Just found, while looking for something else, that in the bash [NEWS](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) for 4.3 there is an entry that says

> b.  There are new bindable commands to search the history for the string of
>       characters between the beginning of the line and the point
>       (history-substring-search-forward, history-substring-search-backward)

So that means with a new enough version of readline (that's in the readline section of the NEWS) you can still have the substring history search with this version.

Comment: I have bound arrow up to `history-search-backward` and arrow down to `history-search-forward`, which is very convenient I find, as I usually want to search on the start of a previous command.

Answer (score 1):

You press "Escape" Key to terminate reverse-i-search. 
I'm speculating here. Since you have enabled **find** in your command line intentionally, the reverse search is triggered.

The reverse search searches index from newest to oldest. Since the `cat fire.txt` is always the recent search, it always shows up first.

Linux Bash now allows forward search using `cntrl + S` and backward search using `cntrl + R` . Please check if your terminal traps `cntrl + S` & `cntrl + Q` for flow control. 
If that's the case you can disable this by using `stty -ixon`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

##### Understanding the question

Not sure whether I understand it right. I do not see a problem, and the answer is already in the first comment, which I put in the middle of this answer at "Cancel without losing console text".

##### Editor: tmux

What is more, if you want to keep a copy of the word "find" and still keep `cat fire.txt`, that is also possible when taking tmux as the editor. *(not tested, but I guess that Alacritty can do that as well, and perhaps many more)*

##### Copy

Go into *Ctrl+B+[* mode to be free to roam around in any field of the console. Press *Space* as the starting marker of the "recursive search text". Press *Enter* at the end marker. If you set mouse on in your config, you can also use the mouse to *Shift+mark* and Copy with *Ctrl+Shift+C*, or you can just mark with the mouse and by this, copy to the tmux clipboard.

##### Cancel without losing console text

Then go back to any console text that you had at the start with *Ctrl+g* as the first comment says it: anything you had written in the console is still there.

##### Paste

And you now can paste the text of the recursive search on top of that, check middle mouse click, *Ctrl+Shift+V*, or look up other ways.

##### Meta noise

This is a cross-site copy of the same answer at [How can I cancel reverse search without losing text typed?](https://superuser.com/a/1743296/1192848).